# access token expiration/renewal

Tags: security, token, facebook-access-token, renewal

I have a personal website on which i want to display my latest facebook comment. Everything works fine, but I'm not sure how the access token expiration works. I have a two months access token, so does it mean that every two months I have to get a new access token and replace the one in my code. If so, it's really not convenient at all... especially since all this is to authorize MYSELF to get my OWN comments.

Is there a way to automatically renew the access token or to get a token that doesn't expire or any other way around this two months expiration thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Facebook documentation you can ping this URL, which will either return the same access token (if there is time left) or a new one (if there is not time left). This will return a string with a token and an expire time.

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=TOKEN`